# Arduino Icon Library

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project and I want to display icons on a NeoMatrix 8x8 panel.

Initially, I went in direction that relied on inheritance, and requested some input on [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57638/custom-classes-redefinition-of-void-error) where I was advised to go another route, and to ask my question elsewhere is it pertained more to C++ than to Arduino.

Instead of relying on inheritance, I was recommended to store my icons in PROGMEM and have the program build the icons from there.

I attempted the approach as much as I could, but I'm not at ease so I'd like some further insight!

- The idea is to have a byte array that composes an 8x8 icon.
- The values are 0-2, each representing a color set in an RGB struct array.

From what I believe I understand, my byte array stored in PROGMEM is read as a pointer, and needs to be accessed using *ppm_read_byte*.

I am unsure on how to handle the RGB struct. When I attempt to read it from PROGMEM, it causes my program to crash. So I removed it from PROGMEM, and the icon displays correctly. My byte array is in PROGMEM, but not the colors.

**I am aware that I have a serious lack of knowledge about pointers which I need to work on...**

Also, the idea is to have a collection of icons, so should I store all my icons (byte arrays and colors) in a header file? Will that not bloat it?

Thank you in advance for insight on this!

**header.h**

```
typedef struct {
  byte r;
  byte g;
  byte b;
} RGB;

const byte PROGMEM WifiIcon[8][8] = {
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1},
  {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
  {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2},
  {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}
};

const RGB WifiIconColors[3] = {
  {0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 200, 61}
};
```

**ESP8266Neomatrix.ino**

```
#include "header.h"

void printIcon(int startPosition, const byte (&icon)[8][8], const RGB (&colors)[3]){  
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      byte currentPixel = pgm_read_byte(&icon[i][j]);     
      const RGB currentColor = colors[currentPixel];

      byte red = currentColor.r;
      byte green = currentColor.g;
      byte blue = currentColor.b;

      matrix.setPixelColor(startPosition++, red, green, blue);      
    }
  }  
}
```

https://gist.github.com/Nate1661/0eea9200e9d1c86187c2acf205ba3602

Comment: Why downvote? I fail to see how the research wasn't sufficient here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the RGB data to reside in PROGMEM, since it is not a native type handled by `pgm_read_XXX` functions, just read it with [`memcpy_P()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#gad92fa2ebe26e65fa424051047d21a0eb):

```
RGB currentColor;
memcpy_P(&currentColor, colors + currentPixel, sizeof(RGB));
```

If this crashes, then perhaps there is an issue with the value of `currentPixel` that you read.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works. I have to read up on this a lot.